# Am I using React hooks wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wanted to create a sevice-like hook that doesn't hold state, it just exports an object with funtions.

I first started with this:

```
export default useFoo = () => ({ // some functions here... });
```

But then I realized that this wouldn't be the best approach because a new object is going to be created every time the hook is called and I don't want that - I need one global object with the same reference across all components, so then I tried this:

```
const foo = { // some functions here... };
export default useFoo = () => foo;
```

It works as expected, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. Is there a better way to achieve this? Or should I use context maybe?

EDIT: I know that I can just export a plain JS object and not bother myself with hooks, but I need it to be a hook because I use other hooks inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works as expected, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

If foo never changes, and doesn't need to close over any values from the other hooks you're calling in `useFoo`, then that's fine. If it *does* need to change based on other values, then you can use `useCallback` and/or `useMemo` to only recreate the object when relevant things change.

```
export default useFoo = () => {
  const something = useSomeHook();

  const foo = useMemo(() => {
    return { /* some functions that use `something` */ }
  }, [something]);

  return foo;
}
```